# Updating list values in nested Dictionary with Loops

Tags: python, list

i need some help with this: i need to update a nested dictionary with the values of a list with looping procedure.

```
aDict = { 'id' :
             {'name': 0 },
             'id2':
             {'foo':0}
            }
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for k, v in aDict.items():
    for keys in v.keys():
        for i in temp:
            aDict[k][keys] = i

print   aDict   

result = {'id2': {'foo': 9}, 'id': {'name': 9}}
```

i need to put in the values of the list temp in sequence into the values of the nested dictionary, but i only get the last value.

Comment: Is this python2? Also what is the expected output You should also know that there can be only one unique value per key, and that value is being overriden in your inner loop You can check that by putting a `print(aDict)` in your innermost loop

Comment: Is this the output you want? : `{'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}, 'id2': {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}}`

Comment: Hello, yes, it's python 2.. the expected result I want is that  {'id': {'name': 1}, 'id2': {'foo': 2}}. iterate each value in temp list.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code as :

```
aDict = { 'id' :
             {'name': 0 },
             'id2':
             {'foo':0}
            }
temp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for k, v in aDict.items():
    for keys in v.keys():
       # for i in temp:
         #   aDict[k][keys] = i
         aDict[k][keys]= [:]
print   (aDict)   

result = {'id': {'name': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}, 'id2': {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}}
```

Just copy the whole list for every key items in your dictionary and you will get the desired output. (as done in code) . Also don't forgot to add parenthesis around print :)